# PowerShell webservice query

Tags: web-services, powershell, soap, powershell-2.0

There is [PS script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Script-to-verify-web-ceb46109) for verifying webservice and it works:

```
$SiteURL = "http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?op=GetCityWeatherByZIP"

$request = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($SiteURL)    
try 
{     
    #Get the response from the requst 
    $response = [Net.HttpWebResponse]$request.GetResponse() 
    Write-Host "The service is running." 
    $request.Abort() 
}     
Catch  
{ 
    Write-Warning "The service of site does not run or maybe you don't have the Credential" 
}
```

But how I can specify query parameter, ZIP?

Comment: Did you even read the page that you referred to? Look at the `HTTP GET` section, and you should be able to piece together what you need to specify a ZIP code into your request.

Comment: where is HTTP GET section on this page?

Comment: @alex near the bottom of http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?op=GetCityWeatherByZIP

Comment: @AdilHindistan, I still don't understand. how I can specify parameter in PS script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## add a $zip parameter to get zip as an input

param($zip)

## update your url to include zip when sending request

$siteURL="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx/GetCityWeatherByZIP?ZIP=**$zip**"

Comment: why I need param($zip)? I can just used use $zip in querystring. I need param if I wrap this code to the function, right?

Comment: Yep, if you want to pass zip as a param to this script or use it as function. Otherwise you can hardcode it of course

Comment: why ?op=GetCityWeatherByZIP replacing /GetCityWeatherByZIP? it look like ?op doesn't work with param.